# Retrieve a time of specific commit in GIT

Tags: git

Does anybody know how to retrieve a time of specific commit in GIT? I want to use it to display in my app build.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here:

```
$ git log --pretty="%h %ad %ar" -1 0805c6f9635d77ece39cd5070a86e3ae8d889d0e

0805c6f Thu Jun 16 15:22:16 2011 +0200 19 minutes ago
```

The `-1` will limit the amount of results to one. To get just the date remove the `%h` and the `%ar` from the log format.